# Catch database errors with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I have the following solution (simplified) using entity framework:

```cs
public class Account
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Email { get; set; } = null!;

}
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; } = null!;

    public DatabaseContext(
        DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : 
        base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Account email unique constraint
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
            .HasIndex(e => e.Email)
            .IsUnique();

    }
}
```

As you can see, I am creating a unique constraint in the `Account.Email`.
I try inserting a new account with an existing email and I can see in the logs (and afterwards in the database as well), that the insert failed.
I tried catching this failed insert as follows, but it seems that the `SaveChangesAsync` method never throws an exception.

```cs
public class WorkUnit
{

    private readonly DatabaseContext context;

    // Omitted dbsets to simplify

    public WorkUnit(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public async Task CommitAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        try
        {
            await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // This catch clause is never reached even though the insert fails
            throw;
        }
    }

}
```

How can I accomplish this? I was thinking in adding an event handler to the `DatabaseContext.SaveChangesFailed` and change a `bool` flag indicating if there was an exception or something like that, but I am concerned of race conditions and overall doesn't seem like a good pattern.

Comment: This should work. Please give a [mcve]. And also tell us what database provider you are using

Comment: Although you really should be catching EF's `DbUpdateException` to specifically handle the exception from the save operation, and look at the inner exception (a `SqlException` if you're using SQL Server) for the code (not the message) for the constraint violation. That way you specifically know that the exception is due to the duplicate e-mail and isn't some other database exception, or even a non-database exception. They need to be handled differently.

Comment: @madreflection That is what I want to do, can you give me an example of how to do it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by handling the Task returned by the SaveChangesAsync.

```cs
    public async Task CommitAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        await context
            .SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken)
            .ContinueWith(PostCommitAsync);
    }
    private async Task PostCommitAsync(Task<int> commitTask)
    {
        if (commitTask.IsFaulted)
        {
            // Handle exception(s) here
            var ex = commitTask.Exception;
        }
        else
        {
            // No exception here, continue as you wish
        }
    }
```